# Line chart is showing under bar in combochart in chartjs

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js, bar-chart

I am using combo chart using chart.js in my website.

The problem I am facing is the line disappears when it meets the bar. I think it is because the line chart is showing below the bar chart.
[image]

PFB the code I used.

var PCTCtx = document.getElementById("pctdiv").getContext("2d");

```
    PCTChart = new Chart(PCTCtx, {
        type: 'bar',
        data: {
            datasets: [{
                label: 'Bar Dataset',
                data: [100, 70, 60, 40],
                backgroundColor: ['red', 'red', 'red', 'red']
            }, {
                label: 'Line Dataset',
                data: [50, 50, 50, 50],
                fill: false,
                backgroundColor: ['#000000', '#000000', '#000000', '#000000'],
                // Changes this dataset to become a line
                type: 'line'
            }],
            labels: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April']
        },
        options:  {
                    scales: {
                        yAxes: [{
                            ticks: {
                                beginAtZero: true
                            },
                            gridLines: {
                                display: false
                            }
                        }],
                        xAxes: [{
                            barThickness: 35,
                            gridLines: {
                                display: false
                            }
                        }]
                    }
                }
    });
    PCTChart.data.datasets[1].borderColor = '#000000';
    PCTChart.update();
```

I need the line to show on the bar chart.

I have created a jsfiddle for the same [here](https://jsfiddle.net/o7wL0j6d/4/)

Any help would be appreciable.

Comment: Hello, maybe the problem is in your data, because as you can see [here](https://jsbin.com/cahumelele/edit?html,js,output) the line is over the bar.

I see in the image that in your x-axis you have "time" data slot, so maybe your line starts at the very end of the day and it doesn't go over the bar for this? 

We need some data to see how the chart is plotted...

Comment: @Margon I have updated the question and added some dummy data, Please check

Comment: I checked your fiddle, so you can do 2 fix to this behaviour first one: [as you can see here](http://www.chartjs.org/samples/latest/charts/combo-bar-line.html), they make the chart with the line dataset as the first one, so it's "above" the bars

Second: you can use opacity in your color bars: like "#FF0000CC", so you can see under the bars

Answer (score 6):

I was facing the same issue. I found an option "order" in the dataset. https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/mixed.html

Comment: [Are answers that just contain links elsewhere really “good answers”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers)

Answer (score 5):

I found the solution my self.

Actually, we need to put the line data above the bar data in the  dataset. the chart.js creates the chart from top to bottom in the order it finds the chartdata in the dataset.

So I changed the code to to below

```
var PCTCtx = document.getElementById("pctdiv").getContext("2d");

    PCTChart = new Chart(PCTCtx, {
        type: 'bar',
        data: {
            datasets: [{
                label: 'Line Dataset',
                data: [50, 50, 50, 50],
                fill: false,
                backgroundColor: ['#000000', '#000000', '#000000', '#000000'],
                // Changes this dataset to become a line
                type: 'line'
            },{
                label: 'Bar Dataset',
                data: [100, 70, 60, 40],
                backgroundColor: ['red', 'red', 'red', 'red']
            }],
            labels: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April']
        },
        options:  {
                    scales: {
                        yAxes: [{
                            ticks: {
                                beginAtZero: true
                            },
                            gridLines: {
                                display: false
                            }
                        }],
                        xAxes: [{
                            barThickness: 35,
                            gridLines: {
                                display: false
                            }
                        }]
                    }
                }
    });
    PCTChart.data.datasets[1].borderColor = '#000000';
```

and it worked for me thankyou

Comment: I was just typing out that very answer :)  +1 for finding the solution yourself and posting it back here to help others.

Answer (score 0):

we can use order to overcome this problem
ex.

```
    label: 'Schedule',
    data: [...lineData],
    borderColor: '#9630D6',
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    type: 'line',
    order: 0,
  },
  {
    label: 'bar 1st',
    data: [...barData1],
    backgroundColor: '#97CEA5',
    barThickness: 40,
    order: 1,
  },
  {
    label: 'bar 2nd',
    data: [...barData2],
    backgroundColor: '#E2BB72',
    barThickness: 40,
    order: 2,
  },

  {
    label: 'bar 3rd',
    data: [...barData3],
    backgroundColor: '#E2E28F',
    barThickness: 40,
    order: 3,
  }
```